# Why ASP.NET Webform not recognizing jQuery Code (CS1056: Unexpected character '$')

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-webpages

i'm quite new to asp.net web forms, i want to add a javascript file containing jquery code in my masterpage.

this is the error
[image]

```
<body>
<form runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
            <%--Framework Scripts--%>
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />

            <%--Site Scripts--%>
            <script runat="server" src="Scripts/MyScripts/LogicMain.js"></script>

        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

*LogicMain.js is the file i want to include in the masterpage because it will run on every page loaded.*

UPDATE:
i tried putting just the alert() in the .js file but its now giving some other error.
[image]

Comment: Syntax doesn't look right there... could also be something before it.  Use something like: $( "#homeLogo" ).mouseenter(function() { ....  (Include more complete JS code in your post)

Comment: You can't do runat="server" with a JavaScript file. JavaScript in Web Forms runs on the client.

Answer (score 1):

remove this line

```
  <script runat="server" src="Scripts/MyScripts/LogicMain.js"></script>
```

from the scripts - put it after `<asp:ScriptManager runat="server">`

Comment: i tried putting the script before and after <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"> but same error shows.

Comment: i try putting it as the last statement in body but still no luck.

Comment: @HassaanRaza I do not know what you have place there, or if you place it to run as c# - you must not get this kind of errors for c sharp files... this is a javascript file, must not pass from the compiler - check why is pass

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution, it depends on two thing,

1. remove runat="server" from the script.
2. add the script after </asp:ScriptManager>

[image]